# How do i add a new key value pair to anywhere i want in the original hash by manipulating it via an external perl file?

Tags: perl

consider the following **hash of hashes** within a **perl task module** as

```
package taskmoduleName; 
use vars qw( %hash);  
%hash = ( 
 'x1' => {  'fruits' => { 
               'candiedfruit' => {  
                   'sugarcoated' => {
                       'fruitname1' => 'grapes',  }, },   
                   'chocolatecoated' {  
                       'fruitname2' => 'cherries', }, },},    
            'vegetables' => {  
                 'fried' => {  
                    'salted' => {     
                       'veg1' => 'banana', }, }, },
'x2' => {    'xyz' => 
                  'xyz1 => 'hhh', },}, );
```

How do i **add a new key value pair** to anywhere i want in the **original hash** by **manipulating it via an external perl file**?
P.S. I do not want to modify anything else in the original file except add the new entries

Comment: Can you be more specific? What entry do you want to add and where?

Comment: Is it your intent to manipulate the code in one perl script with another perl script? Because that does not sound like a good solution at all. There are many better ways to serialize data.

Comment: PPI, eval, Data::Diver, Data::Dumper.

Comment: Do you want to modify the hash at run-time in a script that uses the module?  Or do you want to modify the file itself?

Comment: i want to add the new entry into the taskmodule however i do not want to change anything else in the task module because the task module is used by another module and @choroba say i want to add in 'chocolatecoated' an entry 'fruitname3' => 'cranberry'. Basically i need to know how to traverse the hash and add a new value.

Answer (score 0):

In your other file you can do something like this:

```
use taskmoduleName;
$taskmoduleName{x1}{fruits}{long}{name} = 'rhubarb';
```

However, this likely leads to fragile and hard-to-maintain code, and isn't really recommended.

Why do you need to do something like this? Maybe somebody here can think of a different approach.